configure nginx to work with multilpe ports on same instance
I have 3 express application running in 3 different ports, I want to configure nginx to serve them separately, when I access to

url -> localhost/app1 to port 3000.
url -> localhost/app2 to port 4000.
url -> localhost/app3 to port 5000.

Please help me with this. i tried this with sites-available and sites-enabled as well. but nothing worked.
Example nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /app1/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /app2/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
    location /app3/{
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

When ever I try to access it the chrome tab changes to respective applicaiton title but the screen remains empty. The error in the error log is this.
2024/05/03 23:13:14 [error] 34788#14756: *403 CreateFile() "C:\Users\user1\Downloads\nginx-1.25.5/html/static/js/main.959bf3b9.js" failed (3: The system cannot find the path specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /static/js/main.959bf3b9.js HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/app1/"
